# calling function in a loop for several lists python

Tags: pandas, function, loops

I have written a function in python which takes three input variables. Now I want to call the function on a list of items for each input variables. So the function call is like this:

```
 call_function('cat', 'brown', 2)
```

The lists are:

```
 category_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'squirrel']
 color_list = ['brown', 'black']
 age = [1,2,3]
```

Now I want to run function on each item. So it should return results for cat, brown and 1, and then cat, brown and 2, and then cat, brown and 3 and then cat, black and 1, and then cat, black and 2, and then cat, black and 3 and then do the same for dog and then for squirrel. I know that I will need to call the function in a loop, but I tried and failed several times. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

use `itertools`, it does the job for you, really simple to call the `product` function.

supply the variables to `itertools.product(....))` as paramaters
then `list()` the response.

#### Code

```py
import itertools
category_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'squirrel']
color_list = ['brown', 'black']
age = [1,2,3]

def call_function(category, color, age):
    print(category, color, age)


combinations = list(itertools.product(category_list, color_list, age))
for combintaion in combinations:
    call_function(combintaion[0], combintaion[1], combintaion[2])
```

#### Output

```
cat brown 1
cat brown 2
cat brown 3
cat black 1
cat black 2
cat black 3
dog brown 1
dog brown 2
dog brown 3
dog black 1
dog black 2
dog black 3
squirrel brown 1
squirrel brown 2
squirrel brown 3
squirrel black 1
squirrel black 2
squirrel black 3
```

#### Proof

Test [Here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/)
[image]

#### code for method from itertools

```py
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Comment: where exactly am I calling the function here?

Comment: answer updated, use itertools.product(...)

Comment: gives me this error: TypeError: string indices must be integers. Think it is expecting a string for age

Comment: @user18334254 then you did something wrong, look at my answer for the proof of work

Comment: yes, but while calling the function, each input should be like 

call_function('cat', 'brown', 1), but now I see that it is like
call_function(cat brown 1)

could that be the reason the call is not working?

Comment: @user18334254 notice the commas in the function call `call_function(combintaion[0], combintaion[1], combintaion[2])`

Comment: yes, I gave commas. So maybe missing single quotes for non-numerical list items?

Comment: maybe, the code i provided works correctly as it should, the issue you are having is on your side, post more code to your question and i'll help, but for now, upvote and mark as solution.

Comment: I have provided the exact requirement. The input into function call are two non-numeric and one numeric item. The code should be such a way that when we call the function, each time the non-numeric inputs are enclosed in single quotes and numeric ones not. Otherwsie the call doesnt work. But I will certainly upvote you, as you tried to help

Comment: @user18334254 your function shouldnt be `def call_function('category', 'color', age):` it needs to be `def  call_function(category, color, age):`

Comment: @user18334254 look at the screenshot in my answer, is your code called the exact same way?

Comment: my function needs the input in that way. non-numeric inputs in quotes and numeric ones not

Comment: yes, I was able to replicate your results. but the same doesnt work for my function and it requires inputs in the way I described above

Comment: please look at my question, how I call the function for it to work. I edited to make it clearer

Comment: no reason to call `list` on the result of `product`. it just creates a list when all you need is one element at a time.

Comment: I still get the same error message. TypeError: string indices must be integers. 
Isnt there a way to do it in a loop please?

Comment: @user18334254 i've added the code for that product function to my answer

Comment: same error again, sorry: TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Maybe there is an simpler way to call the function in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

here is another way to do it, using pd.apply, after creating a dataframe using itertools.product

```
import itertools  

category_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'squirrel']
color_list = ['brown', 'black']
age = [1,2,3]

df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    list(itertools.product(
        category_list, color_list, age
    )), columns=['category', 'color', 'age'])

df.apply(lambda row: call_function(row['category'], row['color'], row['age']), axis=1)
```

RESULT:

```
cat brown 1
cat brown 2
cat brown 3
cat black 1
cat black 2
cat black 3
dog brown 1
dog brown 2
dog brown 3
dog black 1
dog black 2
dog black 3
squirrel brown 1
squirrel brown 2
squirrel brown 3
squirrel black 1
squirrel black 2
squirrel black 3
```

if function is named MY_FUNCTION

```
df.apply(lambda row: MY_FUNCTION(row['category'], row['color'], row['age']), axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I get this error: 
       df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Comment: updated solution with the import line

Comment: yes, first thing I did

Comment: added screenshot of my notebook

Comment: ok, I see the output, but I need each output to be called on my_function. my_function(cat, brown, 1), etc How can I put each output as input into my_function and get the report on each combination?

Comment: maybe please look at my question again, I think it may just be easier to run the function in a loop for i, j and k for items in each list and run my function

Comment: you able to run the code? is that a correct assumption?       myfunction does get called for each combination of category, color and age and if you notice, the output has 18 lines for each of these combinations. the function I created was just a dummy function which received the combination and print them out. You plug your function and you receive the output you need

Comment: just to be clear, assuming my function is named my_function, could you tell me where and how I would plug it in? Sorry, I tried a few ways and failed

Comment: I get this error: # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'category'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245894/discussion-between-naveed-and-user18334254).

Comment: I solved it by calling the function in a loop

Comment: for i in category_list:
    for j in color_list:
        for k in age:
            call_function(i,j,k)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling the function in a loop. I am sure there is a more efficient/elegant way to do this, but since my df and lists are small, it works good. Wanted to post my solution for those who are working with small lists and having similar problem. Of course, improvement suggestions are welcome.

```
for i in category_list: 
    for j in color_list: 
        for k in age: 
            call_function(i,j,k)
```